# Unexpected single-quotes in file name

Tags: linux, arch-linux

Original post over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350216/unexpected-single-quote-in-file-name

Basically, it seems that ever since I accidentally overloaded my filesystem (it's not currently and there don't seem to be any errors on disk), I've been seeing single-quotes, only when using `ls` in filenames that have spaces in them. I'm not sure why exactly this is happening. How would I go about changing it back to the way it was?

Comment: coreutils developers were being dumb and breaking nearly 50 years of tradition, that's why. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-was-ls-changed-to-wrap-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes - also explains how to solve it.