# Quoted filenames with spaces in ls output on OSX

Tags: ls

**The problem**

I don't want to see filenames quoted when they contain spaces.

**Example**

On OSX I see this when running `ls`:

```
> ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 mafro staff 68 Mar 16 09:02 'dir with spaces'
drwxr-xr-x 2 mafro staff 68 Mar 16 09:02 dir_with_spaces
```

On my Debian box it looks like this:

```
> ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 mafro mafro 4096 Mar 16 09:02 dir with spaces
drwxr-xr-x 2 mafro mafro 4096 Mar 16 09:02 dir_with_spaces
```

My shell is `zsh` with `prezto` and a tiny amount of my own customisation. I (should) have exactly the same dotfiles on both boxes

Here's `ls`. It's the same on both systems:

```
> which ls
ls: aliased to ls --group-directories-first --color=auto
```

Comment: You'll get the quoting on newer Debian releases, too. See [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick you should make this comment an answer! I've searched high and low for this and didn't find that link you sent :) THANKS

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Debian undid this change in the mailing list because the maintainers agreed with me (asker of the question you linked) that it was a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a new feature of Coreutils `ls`.

From the info documentation:

> ‘-N’
>   ‘--literal’
>   ‘--quoting-style=literal’
>
> Do not quote file names.  However, with ‘ls’ nongraphic characters
>        are still printed as question marks if the output is a terminal and
>        you do not specify the ‘--show-control-chars’ option.

Answer (score 1):

To disable this feature, add `export QUOTING_STYLE=literal` to your `~/.bashrc` or, if you are using recent GNU coreutils with shells that don't support `export var=value`, use:

```
QUOTING_STYLE=literal
export QUOTING_STYLE
```

IMO, the recently added quoting styles are a good feature, but they should not have changed the default behaviour because It breaks too many existing scripts and command line habits - especially for people who are doing the Right Thing and properly quoting their variables.

BTW, Debian reverted the behaviour in coreutils 8.25-2, so it was only present briefly in `sid` in 8.25-1.

Comment: It's still present in Arch Linux, however.

Comment: @ams I feel bad for you.

Comment: Upvoting but I thought I'd point out that the new(ish) output-style is only used when stdout is a terminal so it shouldn't break any scripts – and parsing `ls` was never a good idea: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128987/22812 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs