# How to remove a single quote from a file name?

Tags: files, filenames, rename, escape-characters, mv

I have some podcasts on my radio server which contain a timestamp when they should be played. I noticed one of them is put into single quotes `'filename.mp3'`, and I'm unable to remove them. Check this:

```
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4,0K  4. Apr 20:40 .
4,0K drwxrwsr-x 6 user group 4,0K  4. Apr 20:28 ..
 83M -rw-r--r-- 1 user group  83M  4. Apr 20:32 2016-03-09-22-00-moshtrocity.mp3
173M -rw-r--r-- 1 user group 173M  4. Apr 20:40 2016-03-25-10-00-funkfabrik-classic-25.mp3
 53M -rw-r--r-- 1 user group  53M  4. Apr 20:41 '2016-04-01-21-00-Wasted Fridays.mp3'
```

Now, I tried to escape the `\'` like that, but I get:

```
 $ mv \'2016-04-01-21-00-Wasted\ Fridays.mp3\' 2016-04-01-21-00-Wasted\ Fridays.mp3 
mv: cannot stat ''\''2016-04-01-21-00-Wasted Fridays.mp3'\''': No such file or directory
```

Now, it looks like it ignores the quotes. I tried without, look at this:

```
 $ mv 2016-04-01-21-00-Wasted\ Fridays.mp3 2016-04-01-21-00-Wasted\ Fridays.mp3
mv: '2016-04-01-21-00-Wasted Fridays.mp3' and '2016-04-01-21-00-Wasted Fridays.mp3' are the same file
```

Uh, how to deal with that? How to remove a single quote from a file name?

I'm on ArchLinux if this matters. Filesystem is ext4.

Comment: Is your 'ls' aliased to something? It looks like it may be adding quotes "for" you. Try /bin/ls to compare.

Comment: That's probably it, don_crissti. 5chdn, you can confirm with something like `ls | cat`

Comment: `ls -N` is the [solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/262162/19062). `Is` does some weird stuff. not related to alias. and the file name is intact.

Comment: `ls` no longer does what the user wants or expects, and instead of following the unix tradition has decided to do it's own thing. I'm annoyed too.