# "ls -b" does not work on macOS

Tags: osx, ls

`ls -b` should print the file names with non-printable characters, for example, `ex ex.txt` should be shown as `ex\ ex.txt`, but this does not work on macOS, it is still `ex ex.txt`. Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: What shell are you using?  (`echo $SHELL`)

Comment: Why do you consider a space character to be non-printable?

Comment: I agree that it is printable but the `ls` command does normally treat it that way, at least `ls (GNU coreutils) 8.23` from bash.

Comment: @JuliePelletier latest coreutils introduced an incompatible change to the way `ls` displays filenames. Several distributions have already reverted it but if yours hasn't you now need to include the `-N` flag. Everywhere. See [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes)

Comment: @JuliePelletier I tried all kinds of shells including `bash sh csh ksh tcsh zsh`, so it should not be caused by the shells. I think @StephenKitt answered the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-b` option isn't [standardised](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html), so its behaviour is implementation-dependent.

Many Linux systems use GNU ls by default; it defines the `-b` option as

> print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters

and uses an [elaborate quoting implementation](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/quotearg.c). The space character is a nongraphic character so it ends up being escaped.

On macOS the [definition of `-b`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) is different:

> **-B**      Force printing of non-printable characters (as defined by [`ctype(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/ctype.3.html) and current locale settings)
>                in file names as `\xxx`, where *xxx* is the numeric value of the character in octal.
>
> **-b**      As **-B**, but use C escape codes whenever possible.

The `ctype` functions (or macros) consider that the space character is printable, so it's not escaped.

Comment: A way to mimic the behaviour of Coreutils `ls -b` would likely be `ls -b | sed 's/ /\\ /g'`. I don't have a mac to test this at the moment. This would catch spaces, at least, but I don't know about other characters.

Comment: That would work in some cases, but post-processing the `ls` output is touchy in general because you can’t distinguish between file names and the rest of `ls`’s output.