# How to use wildcard * with 'A long filename'?

Tags: bash

I'm trying escape characters like \' but it doesn't work.

`$ cp 'A long filen* ./short_filename`

Comment: Does the filename include a `'` or did you forget to close the quotes?

Comment: yes, it does. That line doesn't work.

Comment: ...What?  What is the filename?

Comment: 'Really long filename.mp4'

Comment: Sure that it's including the quotes or is it due to the new output from `ls`? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @MIce: Your version of bash doesn't determine your version of `ls`.  You can do `ls --version` (if GNU) to find out

Comment: or try `ls -N` to see file name without additional quoting

Comment: ls (GNU coreutils) 8.28

Your line <code>cp "'A long file"* ./short_file</code> doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ok. ls -N doesn't show quotes

Comment: so it's without quotes. Then just use `cp "A long file n"* short_filename`

Comment: haha. I already copied it. But my doubt was with using *.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file does not contain quotes, it is a new output behavior of `ls`.

See: [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes)

---

You can use

```
cp "A long file n"* short_filename
```

The `*` must be outside the quotes

or escape all spaces (and other special characters like `\`, `;` or `|`, etc.)

```
cp A\ long\ file\ n* short_filename
```

Comment: I chose this answer because it tells about ls behaviour and the two examples work for me. I upvoted the other answer but those votes are recorded because of my reputation.

Answer (score 2):

If the filename includes single quotes you can escape them with `\` or double quotes.  You also have to escape the spaces though:

```
$ touch \'A\ long\ filename\'
$ ll
total 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jesse jesse 0 Jan 11 14:09 'A long filename'
```

You cannot escape the `*` for it to glob though so you must leave it outside the quotes:

```
$ ls -l \'A\ long\ file*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jesse jesse 0 Jan 11 14:09 'A long filename'
$ ls -l "'A long file"*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jesse jesse 0 Jan 11 14:09 'A long filename'
```

---

```
$ cp "'A long file"* ./short_file
$ ll
total 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jesse jesse 0 Jan 11 14:09 'A long filename'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jesse jesse 0 Jan 11 14:11 short_file
```

Comment: Your examples are all with the file name literally being `'A long filename'`, including the single quotes. I suspect OP may just have `A long filename` though, without the quotes. Might want to give an example if that's the case.

Comment: @derobert: OP said the filename contains single quotes

Comment: You're right, I misread that comment. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: No worries, seems like it shouldn't be part of the actual filename but I have seen worse filenames :p

Answer (score 2):

GNU `ls`, at least, can also tell you how to quote something. In more recent versions its on by default, but even going back years you can do something like:

```
$ ls --quoting-style=shell
"'A long filename.mp4'"
```

There are other quoting styles available too; see the `ls` manpage.

You can also do something with `printf` (at least in bash):

```
$ printf '%q\n' *
\'A\ long\ filename.mp4\'
```

The `%q` means to print the argument out quoted (followed by `\n`, a newline), and `*` matches all the file names. So this is a sort-of-ls using printf.

Then after that, you just have to figure out how to add in your `*`. It needs to not be quoted, so in the two styles it'd be:

```
"'A long file"*    # we've just cut a ""-quoted string short.
\'A\ long\ file*   # that's just escapes, so cut it short.
```