# I can see but cannot delete a file

Tags: files, quoting, filenames, rm

I am running Linux Mint.I tried to copy a file with the file manager. It looked like it hung.
I can see the file in the directory with `ls -l`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mike domain^users 20 Mar 1 08:57 'output (copy 1).txt'
```

It has char quotes around it. However, I cannot move it, remove it, cat, etc.
For any of these commands, I get a similar error message. For `rm *`, I get:

```
rm: cannot remove 'output (copy 1).dat':No such file or directory.
```

I moved every other file out of the directory except this one and tried `rm *` and `rm -f *`. Same error.

I tried

```
$ rm "'output (copy 1).dat'"
rm: cannot remove ''\''output (copy 1).dat'\''': No such file or directory
```

I tried

```
$ mv * test
mv: cannot move 'output (copy 1).txt' to 'test': No such file or directory.
```

I can't `rmdir`, it says the directory is not empty.

Ideas?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to remove `output (copy1).dat`?

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/237982

Comment: No. Same error with escape backslashes.

Comment: I tried rm 'output (copy 1).dat', then emptied the directory and tried rm * and rm -f *. No success

Comment: Show the command you're using. [Edit] your question.

Comment: Emptied of all files except this file

Comment: What is the output of: `for f in *; do echo "$f"; done` when run in that directory?

Comment: group name seems a bit peculiar, if you didn't mess `/etc/group` you might have a faulty filesystem. have you tried `fsck` (File System Consistency Check) it ?

Comment: _What commands_ did you use?

Comment: I just tried the for f in *; do echo "$f"; done   The result is output (copy 1).dat  with no quotes.

Comment: @mshepard: Cool, so I think it's safe to say the quotes _have_ been added by `ls`.  Now it would help if you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/503802/edit) your question to include all of the commands you have tried so far and the error messages that each gave.

Comment: I edited the question to include what I consider the most important command: rm *  As noted in the comments, I tried rm with double quotes around the single quote file name. It still says no such file or directory. Are there other commands that may be of use?

Comment: You just mentioned a file called `output (copy 1).dat` in comments, but in the question you have `output (copy1).dat`.  This is different. Try removing the directory that holds this file (assuming you'd want to remove everything in this directory) with `rm -rf dirname`, where `dirname` is the name of the directory.

Comment: I tried rm -rf processes (that's the folder) and got  rm: cannot remove 'processes': Directory not empty.

Comment: What Unix are you actually running here? You've tagged it with Linux.  Are you on an embedded system? An error message from `rm` usually does not contain the word `rmdir`.

Comment: Sorry - I mistyped at first.

Comment: SOLVED: The directory was on a network drive. I connected to it with a windows 10 machine and had no problem deleting the file. Thanks for all your suggestions.