# bash: Replace single quote by two quotes in string

Tags: bash, escape-characters

I have a variable, e.g. `a'b`, containing a single quote which I need to replace by two single quotes before writing it to a file: `a''b`.

The following bash code used to get the job done for me ...

```
line="a'b"
echo "${line//\'/\'\'}" > out.txt
```

... until today when I discovered diverging outputs depending on the version of bash being used:

- GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu): `a''b`
- GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu): `a\'\'b`

I tried to modify the line above in numerous ways but was unable to have it produce the same output `a''b` in both bash shells.

I ended up using a combination of `echo` and `sed` instead,

```
echo "$(echo $line | sed "s/'/''/g")" > out.txt
```

but I am still wondering if the job can be gotten done with a more concise pure bash expression. Can it?

Comment: the first thing that comes to mind is that you don't need the echo.  just `printf "%s\n" $line | sed "s/'/''/g" > out.txt` will do.    BTW, the `echo "${line//\'/\'\'}"` works as desired in bash 5.0.3 for me.

Comment: Thou should never use variables in format argument of `printf`.

Comment: are you parsing the output of `ls`?    if so then a) [don't do that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) and b) run `man ls` and search for `--quoting-style` and c) run `typeset -p QUOTING_STYLE` and d) see [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/7696)

Comment: If you are parsing `ls`, then this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) for at least two reasons.  Firstly because there are many better ways to process a list of files than to parse ls.  Secondly because the need to double any single-quotes probably only arises because you're trying to parse the output of `ls` and then (presumably) use the filenames as arguments to some other program.     What are you actually trying to achieve that you think parsing ls is part of the solution for?

Comment: @pLumo you are right, and I had replaced the `printf` call with an `echo` call by now. Edited the question this way too.

Comment: @cas I am actually processing outputs of git calls, e.g. `git diff -U0 --no-prefix --no-color --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w  ${IN_DIR}`

Comment: @cas the reason why I'm using echo is, that I am in the actual code doing the following: 
`echo "         write(*,*) '$(echo "${line}" | sed "s/'/''/g")'"  >> ${OUT_FILE}`

Answer (score 8):

One of the [changes](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/CHANGES) between bash-4.3-alpha, and the previous version, bash-4.2-release:

> When using the pattern substitution word expansion, bash now runs the
>       replacement string through quote removal, since it allows quotes in that
>       string to act as escape characters.  This is not backwards compatible, so
>       it can be disabled by setting the bash compatibility mode to 4.2.

---

Input:

```
BASH_COMPAT=4.2
line="a'b"
echo "${line//\'/''}"
```

Output:

```
a''b
```

Answer (score 6):

For a method that would work regardless of the version (and shell implementation like ksh93 where it comes from and mksh and zsh which also support it), you can store the pattern and replacement in a variable:

```
pattern="'"
replacement="''"
printf '%s\n' "${line//$pattern/$replacement}"
```

Or

```
q="'"
printf '%s\n' "${line//$q/$q$q}"
```

(note that in `zsh`, the `$pattern` is taken as a fixed string. If you want it to be taken as a wildcard pattern (which doesn't apply here as `$pattern` doesn't contain wildcard characters), you need to replace `$pattern` with `$~pattern`. In other shells, if you want `$pattern`  to be taken as a fixed string, you need to quote it (`${line//"$pattern"/$replacement}`).

Comment: Also: `"${line//\47/\47\47}"`

Comment: @LéaGris this doesn't work for me in Bash 5.1 but a similar ANSI-quoted string does. `"${line//$'\47'/&apos;}"`. Only had to do this because of a syntax highlight bug in my editor that choked on `${line//"'"/&apos;}`