# Is it possible to make a directory literally called ".."

Tags: filesystems, directory

(Not that you would ever want to), is it possible to create a directory with the literal name `..` or `.`? Under most filesystems it is a reserved name, but would it be possible on, say, XFS, JFS, or some other filesystem which permits it? If so, how?

Secondary question: if you manually modified the filesystem without mounting it, could you create a directory like that, and what would be its behaviour?

Comment: It's not a "reserved" name. Your filesystem may actually have `..` and `.` dir entries, but the kernel won't care about them. At least on linux, `cd ..`, `test -d ..`, `test -d .` will work as expected no matter if the filesystem has such a directory entry or not. I'm not able to give you an example now, but I had created a test FUSE "nullfs " fs which implemented a single dir which returned _regular files_ for any name, including `.` and `..`, and did not list any entries (not even `.` or `..`), but the kernel did not care, and everything was fine.

Comment: To keep compat with silly tools, most fs do _fake_ the `.` and `..` entries when listing directories, without actually storing them -- search for `emit_dots` in the linux source.

Comment: I agree with mosvy. Also, you mention *(not that you would ever want to)*. But since you ask the question you probably do want to... Depending on what your purpose is you could create a directory with another name but where it's rather invisible that the name is different. 2 examples: Add a space at the end, use unicode characters that are also displayed as dots but are not dots

Comment: @Garo I was just wondering. It was purely hypothetical

Comment: @Garo even better, spike the file names with ZWJ, ZWNJ or bidi marks: `mkdir /tmp/dots; perl -e 'open my $f, ">", "/tmp/dots/.$_." for map chr, 0x200c, 0x200d, 0x200e, 0x200f'; ls -a /tmp/dots`. Even the infamous [GNU ls quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes) won't show them differently (unless you're using the `C` locale).

Comment: @mosvy can you make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. Because those entries already exist in each directory. You cannot have two entries with the same name.