# Why `ls [0-9]` finds a file called `[0-9]`, and worse, not after `touch 1`?

Tags: bash, wildcards

```bsh
$ mkdir temp && cd temp
$ ls [0-9]
ls: cannot access '[0-9]': No such file or directory
$ touch \[0-9\]
$ ls [0-9]
'[0-9]'
$ touch 1
$ ls
 1  '[0-9]'
$ ls [0-9]
1
```

I find this behavior very surprising. To me, the `[0-9]` glob pattern should only match a file whose name consists of a single numeric digit. But it is also ***sometimes*** matching a file named `[0-9]` itself.

Is this a bug with glob expansion in bash?

Can I disable this, so that `[0-9]` never matches `[0-9]` (as it shouldn't)?

Comment: Bonus question: why did the second-to-last `ls` print a leading space?

Comment: by the way, it works as as you wish in `zsh` by default settings.

Comment: For your bonus question, see [Why does `ls` add a leading whitespace to its output for certain directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553348/why-does-ls-add-a-leading-whitespace-to-its-output-for-certain-directories)

Comment: Related: [Why is nullglob not default?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set the `failglob` option with `shopt -s failglob`:

```
$ ls [2-9]
ls: cannot access '[2-9]': No such file or directory
$ touch '[2-9]'
$ ls [2-9]
[2-9]
$ shopt -s failglob
$ ls [2-9]
bash: no match: [2-9]
```

> Bonus question: why did the second-to-last ls print a leading space?

Because of the new "user-friendly" [default quoting style](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes/258687#258687) of GNU ls:

```
$ touch 1
$ unset QUOTING_STYLE # use the default
$ ls
 1  '[2-9]'
$ QUOTING_STYLE=literal ls
1  [2-9]
$ ls --quoting-style=literal
1  [2-9]
```

Answer (score 3):

From `man bash`:

> ```
> Pathname Expansion
>   After  word  splitting,  unless  the -f option has been set, bash scans
>   each word for the characters *, ?, and [.  If one of  these  characters
>   appears,  then  the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an
>   alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern (see  Pat‐
>   tern  Matching  below).   If  no  matching filenames are found, and the
>   shell option nullglob is not enabled, the word is left  unchanged.
> ```

Note specifically *If no matching filenames are found, and the shell option
nullglob is not enabled, the word is left unchanged*.  That is why your initial test resulted in:

```
ls: cannot access '[0-9]': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Interesting! After reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204944/163490 to learn the difference between `nullglob` (mentioned by you) and `failglob` (mentioned by the other answer), it looks like it is better to set `failglob` than `nullglob` to get my desired behavior, do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I think `failglob` is the way to go.  The man page I quoted goes on to describe that, but since @zevzek already covered that in his answer, credit for that option goes to him.

Comment: Thank you two very much!!