# List directories starting with '

Tags: ubuntu

I have a lot of folders in a directory and some are starting with the character `'`. I would like to remove these.

Example folders

- Folder.A
- 'Folder.B' <-- want to delete this
- 'Folder.C' <-- want to delete this
- Folder.D

I can get help building a string with typing `echo 'My.Folder` and by pressing tab the whole name prints `echo 'My.Folder.With.Full.Path'`. However. If I start typing `echo '*` and press enter I'm getting some kind of input prompt starting with `>`.

Running: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 4.15.0-51-generic

Comment: [Are you sure the character is really there?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/108618).

Comment: Go into the directory and run `ls -Q` and add the output to your question.

Comment: ls -Q shows everything with double quote (no single quote).
ls -N shows everything with no single quote

Answer (score 2):

The `ls -Q` and `ls -N` results mentioned in the question comments indicate that the single quotes are not actually part of the folder names, but added by the program doing the listing, as there apparently is a character in the name that is considered somehow special.

See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/258991) for a more in-depth explanation of what is going on. In short, the `coreutils` developers decided to make `ls` start quoting filenames with special characters in them by default.

The `>` prompt is unrelated: it appears because you had unbalanced quotes when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The shell assumes you're not done with the command line yet and prompts you to write the rest of the quoted section. If you do this, the quoted section will now include an actual newline character within it.