# Line editor ed saves some filenames in single quotes followed by one space

Tags: linux, arch-linux, filenames, manjaro, ed

I'm following *The Unix Programming Environment* exercises
and have encountered some weird issues. While going through the `ed` exercise, when you
just start `ed`, type in the exercise, then do

```
 w poem
```

It saves in the filesystem as `'poem '`
I tested another file, start `ed`, type in some words,

```
w raistlin
```

and it saves as `'raistlin '`
with the same result (filename in single quotes followed by one space), though I tested on a third, and if I start off with the file name it saves as a normal file. Has anyone else seen these results? I know it's a little esoteric, I think I'm probably 1 of 7 people on the whole earth using `ed` this weekend. I'm using Manjaro Arch.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with GNU `ed` nor with the native `ed` on OpenBSD. Where do you see these filenames, is it in the `ls` output? What does `printf '>>%s<<\n' *` output for these files?

Comment: Yes it's in the ls output.  It gets's weirder I switched window managers from dwm to xfce and it seems have gone away. I was using terminator on dwm and now xfce-terminal. So it's a terminal issue???

Comment: Could well be a terminal issue, yes, or something else relating to your graphical desktop setup. I can't unfortunately test identical setups to yours... Does text that you input get modified in a similar way in any other terminal application? (I'm guessing it's not actually related to `ed` but to something that your input is passing through).

Comment: I thought I saw something weird in vi a few weeks ago, but didn't write it down. I'll test on my Debian system as well going back into dwm and testing with a couple of different terminal apps.

Comment: Could you check whether the odd filenames contains Unicode characters? Possibly by `printf '%s\n' PATTERN | od -ah` where `PATTERN` is some pattern that matches at least of the names.

Comment: I think I got it, was putting a trailing space at the end of the filename. @Kusalananda thanks for all the help. I'm not sure if I should be happy or sad for getting all ADD about this.

Comment: Good! If you want to submit an answer to this describing what the issue was and how you resolved it, that would be good. Otherwise we will likely close and/or delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

According to the originating user, they accidentally added a space character at the end of the filename when saving the file in `ed`.

```
w test
```

(extra space typed after the `test` string above)

Doing so will provoke GNU `ls` to add single quotes around the filename in its output.  It would do this to *any* filename that is "unusual".  In this case, because it contains a space character.

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myself myself 6 Mar  9 21:17 'test '
```

You can get GNU `ls` to output unquoted filenames if you wish, using either `ls --literal`, `ls -N`, `ls --quoting-style=literal`, or by setting the environment variable `QUOTING_STYLE` to the string `literal`.  However, since `ls` output is only meant for *looking at*, it doesn't really matter.

Related:

- [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes)
- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it was an extra space after the filename. So when you specify the filename like this.

```
ed poem
```

it works fine. Inside ed be extremely careful when you are typing the commands like this:

```
w poem(enter)
```

... and not:

```
w poem (enter)
```