# Delete file whose filename contains a dollar sign

Tags: linux, special-characters

I have a file named `''$'\t'` in my directory. How do I delete it?
(I suspect the outermost pair of quotes is not part of the filename.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suspect the outermost pair of quotes is not part of the filename

I suspect the filename is just a single tab character. I think you gave us the output of `ls`. Compare [*Why is `ls` suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/108618) In your case `ls` goes even further and uses [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) (`$'…'`) to denote the tab character as `\t`.

If you type exactly `rm ''$'\t'` (in Bash or another shell that supports `$'…'`) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> then you will remove the file. The two leading single-quote characters enclose an empty string and they can be omitted. I used the literal string you got from `ls`, but it could as well be `$'\t'`.

Alternatively (if your shell does not support `$'…'`) `rm '`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>`'` should allow you to put a tab character inside single-quotes. This command should also work.

Comment: Thanks!  The first method worked in bash, but it didn't work in tcsh.

Comment: In tcsh, `rm "\`printf '\t'\`"` should work at least in this particular case. `printf` should support the same escapes as `$'...'` quotes do, but of course it'll treat `%` specially.